# Tracking moving points on a reconstructed plane

Tags: tracking

I would like to track animals moving on a plane from an aerial video. I'm very new to Blender, but believe that there is a way to do this. Up until now, I have managed to solve the camera motion from tracked points on the ground, and reconstructed the plane on which the animals are moving - this is set as the *Floor* of the scene, since it really is just a plane. Now I would like to track the animals - they are small in the footage, so every animal can be tracked by one marker.

My question is as follows: **Can I tell somehow Blender that the animal object is located on the floor, and thus, can I solve its motion from only one track?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Information Download

When you have a point that you have tracked in the *Movie Clip Editor*, you generally use it to solve camera motion. Occasionally, like in a [VFX](https://youtu.be/ufkgkH7O4QA) scenario, one might deploy a style called *Two-point Motion Tracking*. This uses two tracked points, reconstructed as empties that will move on an *X/Y Plane*. In the linked video, the narrator goes on to show that if you have a dowel rod with sharpie at the top and bottom (points for tracking), and you track those points, you can stretch a glowing cylinder between them and make it look like the person is wielding a lightsaber.

### Your Scenario

In your case, you will probably be looking at a type of *One-point Motion Tracking*, except with multiple one points for each scenario.

1. You will want to be happy with your camera track. After tracking the animals, re-solving the camera motion will be a pain to not possible.
2. Track an animal.
3. Go to *Bottom toolbar > Reconstruction menu > Link Empty to Track*. There should now be a *Plain Axes Empty* connected to the *Camera* by a dotted blue line.
4. In the *3D Viewport*, switch to *Local Transform Orientation*.
5. Move the *Empty* as close or as far away from the camera as needed (probably along *Local Z*).
6. Parent your animal (I assume) to the *Empty*.

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

Comment: It helped, thanks! :) Now the marker of the tracked animal appears on the 3D viewport, and moves more or less on the Floor plane. Is it possible to fix the Empty to the Floor, because I think that the distance between the Empty and Camera are fixed now, and - since the height of the camera changes slightly - the Empty goes sometimes below the plane and sometimes above a bit.

Comment: @KatalinOzogany Glad to help! If you liked my answer, please consider accepting it by selecting the checkmark in its upper, left-hand corner. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!

Comment: Is it possible to fix the Empty to the Floor? The height of the camera changes slightly, and the Empty goes sometimes below the plane and sometimes above a bit, since the distance of the Empty and the Camera are fixed.

Comment: @KatalinOzogany You could go to the _Properties panel > Object Constraints tab > Follow Track constraint_ and click _Constraint to F-Curve_. Then, to to a frame in the _Timeline_ where you like the _Z-Axis_ Position of the empty in question. After that, key `N` to toggle open/close the _3D Viewport Properties Panel_ and go to the _Transform tab_. Right click on the _Z: Location_ Field and choose _Clear Single Keyframes_.

Comment: @KatalinOzogany Glad to help!